# Is there a way to estimate how much memory will PHP array consume?

Tags: php, pdo

Suppose that you have a query and you know exactly how many results it will return and length of every column, e.g. 1M records `` int `id`, char(100) `uid` ``.

Is there a way to know in advance how much memory will PHP need to allocate for this associative array?

Comment: Interesting reading: http://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html

Comment: Depends on the version of PHP but returning a million records is likely to break the bank. Consider SPLFixedArray rather than a standard PHP array if you have to return a million records (especially as you know the number in advance); or consider processing each record as it's fetched

Comment: If you expect your queries to have so large result sets, just say no. Stream the results and handle them in chunks.

Comment: It seems like `SplFixedArray` is certainly a nice option if streaming is not possible. Though, in my case, I am fairly flexible to change the code logic. Nevertheless, question is about whether there is a way to estimate the array size. Blog post does somewhat answer my question.

Comment: try using `memory_get_usage()` before and after populating the array, get the difference. Don't know of a way to calculate beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't allocate 1M records as an associative array. Select only data you need.

Comment: Indeed, the PHP implementation is only doing this gross wastes of memory because the PHP use case does not need 1 million records at the same time lol

Comment: Not an answer to the question. 1M records was only a theoretical example.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to find out would be to do something like:

```
$numItems = 1000000;
$bytes = memory_get_usage();
$arr = array();
$arrBytes = memory_get_usage() - $bytes;
$arr[] = array('id'=>1,'uid'=>str_repeat("a",100));
$itemBytes = memory_get_usage() - $bytes - $arrBytes;
echo "Total memory usage estimate: ".($arrBytes + ($itemBytes * $numItems));
```

Disclaimer: I'm not completely sure how accurate this will be but should give a ballpark. This will also vary on different systems (i.e. 32bit ints versus 64 bit ints) and different encodings (i.e. single byte versus multi byte).

Having said all this (and as @YourCommonSense noted). The answer to "how much memory will a million item array consume" is "too much". Consider paginating or the like to reduce the number of items you need.